# Use different color only for the histogram breaks

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below:

```
result<-floor(runif(100,100,110))
df<-data.frame(result)
```

which I use to create a histogram with breaks the first 10 rows of the 5th column of `df`.

```
h <- hist(df$result, plot=FALSE)
cuts <- cut(h$breaks, c(-Inf,unique(df[1:10,5]),Inf))
plot(h, col=c("blue","darkblue","blue")[cuts])
```

I would like to color with `blue` all the histogram bars except of the `breaks` values which should be `darkblue`. But I do not think I do it correctly as I also take white bars.

this is what I want:
[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, do you want "blue" bars, and the separating vertical lines with "darkblue"? Something like `hist(x = df$result, col = "blue", border = "darkblue")`?

Comment: all the bars must be blue except of the breaks bars which should be darkblue

Comment: @firmo23 When you say the breaks bar do you mean the contour of the bars? I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: the bars that correspond to the 5 values used as breaks. The inside color....whole of it...

Comment: @firmo23 but `h$breaks [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109` has 10 values

Comment: I have `set.seed(1234)` to make the code reproducible and there are more than 5 breaks, `h$breaks` returns ` [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109`

Comment: The values used as breaks, by definition, give *all* bars. Also, why `x1` to `x4`? What is their purpose?

Comment: sorry i meant 10

Comment: if you want alternate colors, just use `col=c("blue","darkblue")`.

Comment: and how the breaks are specified in this? I added a picture as example

Comment: is this clear now?

Comment: yes exactly!tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(result=floor(rnorm(1000, 100, 20)))    
h <- hist(df$result, plot=FALSE, breaks=20)

# Selected breaks
brks <- c(80,85,90)

cols <- rep("lightblue", length(h$breaks))
# Find bars corresponding to breaks
brk_bars <- h$breaks %in% brks
cols[brk_bars] <- "darkblue"

plot(h, col=cols, main="")
```

[image]